# Does submitting consent screen for verification automatically trigger unverified app screen?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

**Update: I can confirm that simply requesting verification, as long as the scope isn't used in the app, does not trigger the unverified app screen.**

The current documentation for when the "unverified app" screen is displayed is slightly confusing.

In particular, what happens when I add a sensitive scope via the Oauth Consent Screen, request verification, but **do not** use it in the app yet?

The unclear part of the [support page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en&authuser=1) is below, in particular point #2:

> The app or script might display an "unverified app" screen before it
>   displays the consent screen. This is based on the specific scopes that
>   your app includes in the request. This warning will display when:
>
> 1. Your app uses sensitive scopes and you haven't configured your OAuth
>      Consent Screen and requested verification.
> 2. **You selected sensitive scopes on the OAuth Consent Screen and requested verification, but the verification is in not yet complete.**
> 3. Your app uses sensitive scopes that you haven't selected on the OAuth Consent Screen configuration page.

The way bullet #2 is worded reads like this may trigger the unverified app screen for users, even though the scope isn't in use.

I may be missing something, but it feels like the intended behavior is to allow users to request verification and only show the "unverified app" screen if the scope is also in use in the app, so as to allow developers to get a scope verified before using it in the app.

Comment: Tip: Don't use sensitive scopes at all. Google is very particular on what apps will get approved and most will not be approved.

Comment: What do you mean by sensitive scope? can you mention scopes?

Comment: The scope in question is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`. Sensitive scopes are scopes that require verification by Google, according to [their help page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?authuser=1). Worth noting that our app already uses numerous sensitive scopes that were verified in the past, before the new workflow was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

After we went ahead and requested verification I can confirm that simply requesting verification does not trigger the unverified app screen, as long as the scope isn't used in the app until it's verified.